# How to upload a complete Pycharm project folder that contains more than 100MB files

Tags: git, github, pycharm, dataset, git-lfs

Im new to github
I have tried uploading small projects to the repo
I used direct drag and drop to upload files and it worked

But when it comes to huge files it just shows up errors

1. How can i add huge files that is more than 100MB
2. Can we add a single folder with huge files together at once?(it also contains subfolders and files are more than 100MB

i tried using the below

echo "# python_project" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/hija-happy/python_project.git
git push -u origin main

I have even referred some youtube videos but still it shows errors and warning

My project is based on Object detection
SO the " dataset " file and "yolo weight" files are more than 100MB

How can i upload all of them without errors
The total file is of 1.44 GB

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as such so other people can find it more easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per GitHub's [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-git-large-file-storage),

> GitHub limits the size of files allowed in repositories. To track
> files beyond this limit, you can use Git Large File Storage.

You can see in the link above, that the maximum file size is limited based on your GitHub plan.

Furthermore, per this [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-files/adding-a-file-to-a-repository), you are limited to file sizes of 100MB each.

> Files that you add to a repository via a browser are limited to 25 MiB
> per file. You can add larger files, up to 100 MiB each, via the
> command line. For more information, see "Adding a file to a repository
> using the command line." To add files larger than 100 MiB, you must
> use Git Large File Storage. For more information, see "About large
> files on GitHub."